# Do I need certificates for each app?

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have read about it so much and i couldn't find a specific direct answer.

Each app must have its provisioning for development and distribution. The provisioning is using the certificates I already have.

- Do I need to create a new certificate(dev/distribute) for each new app, and connect the provisioning to that specific certificate?
- Do I need to create the certificates for dev/distribution and connect them to the provisioning dev/distribution?

I have read about it here, and it wasn't clear to me: [iOS Developer Library: Creating Your Signing Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/CodeSigningYourApps/CodeSigningYourApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH23-SW1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a developer, you create a *single* Development certificate. You can create *many* development profiles (one dev profile per app) that use this certificate.

The same principle applies to Distribution certificates (single certificate, multiple profiles), however you only have one Distribution certificate per iOS Development account (not per developer).

Comment: still dont get it . now even more. correct me if i am wrong: i need to have 1 certificate for dev and one for distribution for all apps. than, every new app has a new provisioning, that connects with these two certificates ??

Comment: @Curnelious that's my understanding so far. 1 dev cert and 1 distrubution cert. which links to new app's provisioning profiles right? only the provisioning profiles are the ones we are creating by again and again for new apps . and the dev cert and development cert are the ones we create only once isn't it?